# Программа не содержит статического метода "Main", подходящего для точки входа

Tags: c#

Ошибка:

```
Программа не содержит статического метода "Main", подходящего для точки входа.
```

Код mainform.Designer.cs:

```
 namespace LZ4
    {
        partial class mainform
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
                this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
                this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
                this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
                this.tabPage2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
                this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
                this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).BeginInit();
                this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
                this.tabPage1.SuspendLayout();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // label1
                // 
                this.label1.AutoSize = true;
                this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(295, 292);
                this.label1.Name = "label1";
                this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(185, 25);
                this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.label1.Text = "Автор: Alrott SlimRG";
                // 
                // trackBar1
                // 
                this.trackBar1.LargeChange = 1;
                this.trackBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(87, 27);
                this.trackBar1.Maximum = 1;
                this.trackBar1.Name = "trackBar1";
                this.trackBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 45);
                this.trackBar1.TabIndex = 2;
                // 
                // label3
                // 
                this.label3.AutoSize = true;
                this.label3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 26);
                this.label3.Name = "label3";
                this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 25);
                this.label3.TabIndex = 3;
                this.label3.Text = "Файл";
                // 
                // label4
                // 
                this.label4.AutoSize = true;
                this.label4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(183, 26);
                this.label4.Name = "label4";
                this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(66, 25);
                this.label4.TabIndex = 4;
                this.label4.Text = "Папка";
                // 
                // label2
                // 
                this.label2.AutoSize = true;
                this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 89);
                this.label2.Name = "label2";
                this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 25);
                this.label2.TabIndex = 5;
                this.label2.Text = "Путь:";
                // 
                // textBox1
                // 
                this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(87, 95);
                this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
                this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(337, 20);
                this.textBox1.TabIndex = 6;
                // 
                // checkBox1
                // 
                this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
                this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 130);
                this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
                this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 17);
                this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 7;
                this.checkBox1.Text = "Зашифровать с паролем";
                this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // label5
                // 
                this.label5.AutoSize = true;
                this.label5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 161);
                this.label5.Name = "label5";
                this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(82, 25);
                this.label5.TabIndex = 8;
                this.label5.Text = "Пароль:";
                // 
                // textBox2
                // 
                this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(113, 167);
                this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
                this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(311, 20);
                this.textBox2.TabIndex = 9;
                // 
                // tabControl1
                // 
                this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
                this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
                this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 8);
                this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
                this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(491, 346);
                this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 10;
                // 
                // tabPage1
                // 
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.progressBar1);
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.label4);
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.trackBar1);
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.label3);
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.label5);
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
                this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
                this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
                this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
                this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
                this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(483, 320);
                this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.tabPage1.Text = "Сжатие";
                this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // tabPage2
                // 
                this.tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
                this.tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
                this.tabPage2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
                this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(483, 320);
                this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;
                this.tabPage2.Text = "Распаковка";
                this.tabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // progressBar1
                // 
                this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 226);
                this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
                this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(395, 23);
                this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 10;
                // 
                // button1
                // 
                this.button1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
                this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(430, 95);
                this.button1.Name = "button1";
                this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(34, 20);
                this.button1.TabIndex = 11;
                this.button1.Text = "...";
                this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // mainform
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(516, 363);
                this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
                this.Name = "mainform";
                this.Text = "LZ4 achivator v 0.4 BETA";
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).EndInit();
                this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.tabPage1.PerformLayout();
                this.ResumeLayout(false);

            }

            #endregion

            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage2;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar1;
        }
    }
```

Код mainform.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LZ4
{
    public partial class mainform : Form
    {
        public mainform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        }
}
```

P.S. Я новичок, так что могу допустить глупейшую ошибку

Также хотелось бы узнать - где здесь писать свой код

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95312/discussion-on-question-by-alrott-slimrg-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто создать новый `Windows Forms` проект. Переименовать `Form1.cs` в `MainForm.cs` (автоматом переименуется и `MainForm.Designer.cs`). В этом проекте взять тело класса, который ты выложил (без `partial class mainform`). И вставить его в тело класса в `MainForm.Designer.cs`.

Создать можно конечно и проект с нуля, руками туда набросать все классы, но для этого нужно писать более длинную инструкцию. Да и зачем.

Это вообще автоматически генерируемый код Visual Studio, когда руками компоненты на форме размещаешь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]